# How can I compute this probability?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

How can I find this probability ?

$\mathbb{P}\left\lbrace \dfrac{1}{(1+\underset{v}{\text{min}}{\vert u-v\vert)^{4}}}+\dfrac{1}{(1+\underset{v}{\text{min}}{\vert u'-v\vert)^{4}}}-\dfrac{2}{(1+\underset{v}{\text{min}}{\vert u-v\vert)^{4}}(1+\underset{v}{\text{min}}{\vert u'-v'\vert)^{4}}}> t \right\rbrace$.

To be more clear, the model is given as follows. I consider two sets of nodes. The first set $S_{n}$ contain n nodes that are uniformly distributed in [0, 1]. The set $S_{N}$ contain N nodes are also uniformly distributed in [0, 1].

$u, v \in S_{n}$ and $u', v' \in  S_{N}$ and $t$ is a real number.  $\vert u-v \vert$ here is the distance between the nodes.

It is possible to use upper bounds inequality if this can simplify.

Thanks for any helpful answers!

Comment: If the minimum is taken over $v$, then isn't $\min|u-v|=0$?

Comment: Could you explain what min exactly means here? My doubt is after you have randomly chosen u,v, u', v is fixed. Then what is the point of a minimum ?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As the comments show, it is not clear what you mean by "the minimum is taken over $v$".

Comment: I updated the post. I hope it is more clear.

Comment: Start by getting the distribution of $\underset{u,v}{\text{min}}{\vert u-v\vert}$

Comment: @didgogns, the minimum is over $v$ only. $u$ is fixed. what if find the  the average distance between two random points ?

Comment: Why isn't $\min_v|u-v|$ just $0$?